# jcifs bad username & password on macos shares

Tags: java, jcifs

I am connecting to a network shared folder using:

```
String url = "smb://"+ip+"/"+shareName+"/";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, usr, pass);
SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
```

This works for connecting to PCs, but trying to connect to a mac gives the error

`jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

However, connecting to `smb://ip_address` and logging in with the same credentials works. I have seen some things indicating that null may not be a valid domain name for macos, but have not seen anything that would work.

**Edit:**

I've been told that the "Computer Name" in sharing preferences is the domain name. However, replacing null with my-computer.local does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MacOS is using SMB2, which is not supported by the jCIFS, so you cannot use this to logon macOS

Comment: Can you make this a little easier for people, who aren't as 'knowledgable' as you, to understand? (thx)